# How do i load and read the excel to my GUI?

Tags: excel, matlab

I already had a GUI which solves formula for

- power,
- h,
- q,
- elevation.

My problem now is how do I read all the data in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) (the table of data is already in excel). And whatever the result in the GUI will match the table of data in excel?

1. For example, result on GUI is 750.
2. Then my table (table data below) will read the excel and give the corresponding equivalent such as 750 equivalent will be 250:

   > H EL
   >   800 300
   >   775 280
   >   750 250
   >   725 175
   >   700 100

sample code :

```
a = get(handles.input1_gamma,'String'); %GAMMA
b = get(handles.input2_h,'String');    %H
c = get(handles.input3_q,'String');     %Q
d = get(handles.input4_power,'String');  %POWER
e = get(handles.input5_eout,'String');
% a and b are variables of Strings type, and need to be converted 
% to variables of Number type before they can be added together
out = str2num(b) + str2num(e);
set(handles.equalel,'String',out);
```

Answer (score 0):

doc xlsread

read the data from excel, then load it into you GUI

Comment: any sample of algorithm on that sir? i am new on matlab

Comment: @user1108932, if you look at doc xlsread, you will see examples reading excel data. So, from your GUI code, call xlsread into a variable, then display it using say uitable in the GUI. If you read documentation on both of these, and then get stuck again in how to implement the code, you can ask again. If you google around, there are lots of examples also.

Comment: my main problem now sir...when i get result it will read the excel and represent the equivalent row value on the table

Answer (score 0):

Matlab by default can parse a XLS file with xlsread.  You can then parse that file in Matlab and read any value you like.

If you want to create a table in Matlab I suggest you  look up the UITable graphical element.

Comment: any sample of algorithm on that sir? i am new on matlab

Comment: my main problem now sir?, when i get result it will read the excel and represent the equivalent row value on the table ?

Comment: xlsread can only read from a saved xls file, it cannot retrieve data from a running instance of excel.  If you want to do that you probably need to set something up using VB scripting

Comment: yeah the file and table is already on the excel its being done manually.. i wanted to get the equivalent row value if i get result? would u think sir matlab can carry do it?